# git access permissions to repository files or paths

Tags: git

How would one prevent certain users from modifying certain paths or files in a repository? Actually, as I see it, this is something that would be controlled by the repository server (through hooks?) but also some local client policy control would be nice, as a way to warn users beforehand.

I understand that user/role management is not part of git, but I'm sure there are tools and scripts out there that people are using to do this kind of control. Unfortunately I can't find almost any information on the subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have hooks on client side as well to do the check ( ie in the git/hooks on the local clone. It can be a pre-commit hook - https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

You can also consider using [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/wiki/) for such purposes.

Comment: I highly recommend gitolite for access control. There is no comparable open source solution available for git at this time. And of course, there's no reason to rewrite it by making your own access control hooks.

Comment: Gitolite sounds like what I'm looking for. I'll take a look, thanks!